# Plot with color corresponding to label

Tags: plot, octave

I have a matrix which looks like this:

```
0.3234 0.5432
0.0283 0.432
0.1234 0.4562
...
```

And a vector that contains a value for each line in the matrix, looking like this:

```
1
3
1
2
...
```

I already found out how to plot my dot map:

```
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2), '.'), axis([0 1 0 1]);
```

What I want to do now is going one step further: I want each dot in my plot to be drawn in a different color, depending on the vector which contains information for each line in the matrix, e.g:

- The first entry in the vector is 1, the dot at [0.3234 0.5432] shall be red
- The second entry in the vector is 3, the dot at [0.0283 0.432] shall be blue
- ...

How do I do that?

Edit:
This is what I have now (I'm using four labels now, but it also did not work with three):

```
labels = csvread('labels.txt');
c = [1 0 0 0
     0 1 0 0
     0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 1];

scatter (data(:,1), data(:,2), 8, c(labels, :), "filled");
grid on
print ("out.png")
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error: invalid value for array property "facevertexcdata"
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/plot/draw/private/__scatter__.m at line 177, column 11
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/plot/draw/scatter.m at line 86, column 10
error:   /home/bryan/octave/test.m at line 64, column 1
```

Comment: In my example c is a matrix holding RGB colors and thus has 3 columns for Red, Green, Blue. In your code above you made a 4x4 matrix for c which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scatter for a "dot map":
**Edit: I've updated my example to uses more colors**

```
d = [0.3234 0.5432
     0.0283 0.432
     0.1234 0.4562
     0.4 0.5
     0.3 0.46
     0.2 0.5];

v= [1;3;1;2;5;4];

c = [1 0 0   #red     (index 1)
     0 1 0   #green   (index 2)
     0 0 1   #blue    (index 3)
     1 1 0   #yellow  (index 4)
     1 0 1]; #magenta (index 5)

scatter (d(:,1), d(:,2), 8, c(v, :), "filled")
grid on
print ("out.png")
```

[image: Created scatter plot]

d is your data, I added one line to show a blue dot, v your "value vector", and c a colormap with your colors which needs to be a nx3 RGB matrix. I've added some more colors.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited the starting post to show the kind of error I'm getting.

Comment: Question: I see that the colors are being chosen from the input-combination of c. How can I use even more colors?

Comment: The columns of c are values for Red, Green, Blue. You can add more colors manually while adding more columns or you can use one of the predefined colormap. See "colormap" or jet, winter, autumn and so on.